# how to pass splited wav file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio

Here is my code for audio file splitting and then do feature extraction on it

```
Filename=uigetfile('*.wav','Select the MATLAB code file');
disp(Filename)
[y, fs]=wavread(Filename);
t1=[1/fs:1/fs:length(y)/fs];
fprintf('Duration orignl = %g seconds\n', length(y)/fs);
nsamples = 20 * fs;
[y2, fs] = wavread(Filename, nsamples);
t2=[1/fs:1/fs:length(y2)/fs];
fprintf('Duration splited = %g seconds\n', length(y2)/fs);
figure,ax(1)=subplot(3,1,1);plot(t1,y);title('orgnl');title(Filename);xlabel('Time (sec)');
ax(2)=subplot(3,1,2);plot(t2,y2);title('splited');title('splited');xlabel('Time (sec)');

a = miraudio(Filename);
z = mirzerocross(a)
```

But here in `a=miraudio(Filename);` it takes original wav file not splited. If I take `a = miraudio(y2);`

It gives me wrong value. can any one help me??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the "wrong value" you get?

Comment: perhaps `a = miraudio(y2,fs);`?